# How to solve T(n) = T(n-3)+n^2 using iteration?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

How can I solve T(n) = T(n-3)+n^2 using iteration?By master theorem answer is O(n^3) but I am having trouble solving it by iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By direct resolution of the recurrence:**

This is a linear recurrence of the first order. We first solve the homogeneous part,

```
T(n) = T(n - 3)
```

which is solved by a constant (more precisely three constants as three intertwined sequences form the solution).

Now for the non-homogeneous part, we use the Ansatz `T(n) = an³ + bn² + cn + d`, because we know that the difference of two cubic polynomials is a quadratic one.

Then

```
a(n³ - (n-3)³) + b(n² - (n-3)²) + c(n - (n-3)) = 9an² + 3(-9a + 2b)n + 3(9a - 3b + c) = n²
```

gives

```
a = 1/9, b = 1/2, c = 1/2.
```

Finally

```
T(n) = (2n³ + 9n² + 9n)/18 + T(0)
```

and similarly for the two other sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to expand the equation:

```
T(n) = n^2 + (n-3)^2 + (n-6)^2 + ... + 1 = \Theta(n^3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
T(3) = T(0) + 3²
T(6) = T(3) + 6² = T(0) + 3² + 6²
T(9) = T(6) + 9² = T(0) + 3² + 6² + 9²
...
```

More generally, `T(3N)` is the sum of `T(0)` and nine times the sum of the squared naturals up to `N`. The well-known Faulhaber formula justifies `O(N³)`.

Similar results hold for `T(3N+1)` and `T(3N+2)`.